# Use TMonthCalendar for months and years only

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe3

My point is I want to keep the calendar always on the months view, like this:

Expected TMonthCalendar view:

[image]

So that when I click in a month, instead of showing the days of the month, it stays in this screen and call the event.

Comment: Pick a language first please. Answers may differ for [tag:delphi] and [tag:c++].

Comment: I'm working in C++ but i may adapt from delphi so is more of a theoretical question.

Comment: _"so is more of a theoretical question"_ This would be rejected as _too broad_, you have to be specific. Please remove the delphi tag, or even both c++ and delphi. You may ask about how to control the behavior of that specific vcl component then.

Comment: Well, it´s all about disable the behavior that switch the view from months to days. I did no found a way after a few hours research. Thanks for the help editing the post anyways.

Comment: If you don't mind the control animating views back and forth, send a MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW after clicks and key presses.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz thanks, I was not aware of `MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW`, I also see a `MCN_VIEWCHANGE` notification, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Vista, the underlying [Win32 MonthCal control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/month-calendar-control-reference) that [`TMonthCalendar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar) wraps has no concept of views at all, so you can't do what you are asking for in XP and earlier, unless you find a 3rd party calendar that supports what you want on those Windows versions.

However, in Vista and later, the underlying MonthCal control is view-aware (but `TMonthCalendar` itself is not).  You can manually send a [`MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/mcm-setcurrentview) message to the `TMonthCalendar`'s `HWND` to set its initial view to `MCMV_YEAR`, and subclass its `WindowProc` property to intercept `CN_NOTIFY` messages (the VCL's wrapper for [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-notify)) looking for the [`MCN_VIEWCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/mcn-viewchange) notification when the user changes the active view.  You can't lock the control to a specific view, but you can react to when the user changes the active view from the Year view to the Month view, and then you can reset the calendar back to the Year view if needed.

For example:

```cpp
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
__published:
    TMonthCalendar *MonthCalendar1;
    ...
private:
    TWndMethod PrevMonthCalWndProc;
    void __fastcall MonthCalWndProc(TMessage &Message);
    ...
public:
    __fastcall TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    ...
};
```

```cpp
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <Commctrl.h>

#ifndef MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW

#define MCMV_MONTH      0
#define MCMV_YEAR       1

#define MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW (MCM_FIRST + 32)
#define MCN_VIEWCHANGE     (MCN_FIRST - 4) // -750

typedef struct tagNMVIEWCHANGE
{
    NMHDR           nmhdr;
    DWORD           dwOldView;
    DWORD           dwNewView;
} NMVIEWCHANGE, *LPNMVIEWCHANGE;

#endif

__fastcall TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6)
    {
        SendMessage(MonthCalendar1->Handle, MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW, 0, MCMV_YEAR);
        PrevMonthCalWndProc = MonthCalendar1->WindowProc;
        MonthCalendar1->WindowProc = MonthCalWndProc;
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::MonthCalWndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    PrevMonthCalWndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg == CN_NOTIFY)
    {
        if (reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(Message.LParam)->code == MCN_VIEWCHANGE)
        {
            LPNMVIEWCHANGE lpNMViewChange = static_cast<LPNMVIEWCHANGE>(Message.LParam);
            if ((lpNMViewChange->dwOldView == MCMV_YEAR) && (lpNMViewChange->dwNewView == MCMV_MONTH))
            {
                // do something ...
                SendMessage(MonthCalendar1->Handle, MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW, 0, MCMV_YEAR);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using C++Builder 10.1 Berlin or later, look at the newer [`TCalendarView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCalendars.TCalendarView) and [`TCalendarPicker`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCalendars.TCalendarPicker) components.  They both have a `DisplayMode` property that you can set to `TDisplayMode::dmYear` for the current view, and an `On(Calendar)ChangeView` event to react to view changes by the user.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using C++Builder XE3, which does not have this components available.

Comment: @GabrielFasoliSusin I updated my answer to something that should work in XE3, provided you don't need to support XP or earlier Windows versions.

Comment: I guess this is as close as I can get from what I need, still have to evaluate if the transitions won't be a problem though. Anyways, thank you for the help.